# What is the function of the @ symbol in Latex code?

Tags: latex, symbols

I have seen severals times in Latex that the @ symbol was used, but I was unable to figure out what its function is. Is this an operator? Here an example:

```
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage%
    \if@twoside%
        \ifodd\c@page%
        \else%
            \thispagestyle{empty}%
            \vspace*{\fill}%
            \newpage%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}
```

Comment: It is part of the macro name. Per tradition, macros which are used internally by a class or a package, have it in their name. This usually indicates that they aren't meant to be directly used by the user.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6240/why-do-latex-internal-commands-have-an-in-them

Comment: So in the upper example ```@twoside``` is a macro that is defined via the code line ```\def\@twoside{%...%}``` and obviously has to return a boolean?

Comment: more likely via something like `\newif\if@twoside` and then set to true via `\@twosidetrue`